# Google Maps query string issue

Tags: google-maps

I want to create a string that gets a route on Google Maps. I can do this with 2 points as follows;

https://maps.google.com/maps?q=51.590846,-0.549313%20to%2051.67209,-0.605159

...but I cannot seem to add a 3rd or 4th point. I know its easy to manually add points but I have to do this in a string so that a user opens the route from my string.

- any help appreciated

thanks

Comment: Just add more [to:'s](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=51.590846,-0.549313%20to:%2051.640687,-0.473335%20to:%2051.67209,-0.605159)

Answer (score 0):

Adding extra destinations can be done in a couple of ways:

- add more +to: lines like this:

https://maps.google.com/maps?q=51.590846,-0.549313%20+to:%2051.67209,-0.605159%20+to:%2051.590846,-0.549313

- use saddr=, daddr=, mrad= like this:

https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=51.590846,-0.549313&mrad=51.67209,-0.605159&daddr=51.590846,-0.549313